# What is UITouchPhase?

Tags: ios, events, uikit

There is `UITouchPhaseBegan` and `UITouchPhaseEnd`, but what is `UITouchPhase`?

Comment: Shouldn't the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITouch_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UITouchPhaseBegan) have a thorough enough explanation?

Comment: `UITouchPhaseBegan` - a finger touch screen, `UITouchPhaseEnd` - a finger lifted from screen. Therefore I can suggest that `UITouchPhase` it is while a finger onto screen (between user touch screen and lifted  a finger from screen). 

A `UITouch` object represents the presence or movement of a finger on the screen.

From the described above, the `UITouchPhase` and `UITouch` is the 'same' (both are between user touch screen and lifted  a finger from screen).

Comment: But (from apple documentation): "...The objects in the set represent those touche **s** that are new or have changed for the phase..." [Event Handling Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/MultitouchEvents/MultitouchEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH3-SW1). 

Why touche **s**? And how `aTouch.tapCount` can be > 2, if touch is **object represents the presence or movement of a finger on the screen**

Answer (score 2):

It is a typedef enum of constants.
See the **UITouch Class Reference**

**Touch Phase**

The phase of a finger touch.

```
typedef enum {
   UITouchPhaseBegan,
   UITouchPhaseMoved,
   UITouchPhaseStationary,
   UITouchPhaseEnded,
   UITouchPhaseCancelled,
} UITouchPhase;
```